# Can a question have "too many tags"?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

[This suggested edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/4567), which entails adding one tag to a question with three tags on it, was rejected for the following reason:

> this question has too many tags already.

The question was subsequently edited by the same reviewer to remove all but one tag.  Can a question have "too many tags"?  I don't quite see a problem here.  Besides, the system does not allow any question to have more than five tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While a single question can't have 'too many tags', *per se* (aside from the hard limit of five tags), in this case, most of the removed tags were removed because they were unnecessary.

In general, we don't do 'hierarchical' or 'categorical' tagging of the sort that was applied to this question ([neogeo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neogeo), [fighting-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fighting-games)), using those broader tags only to indicate questions in which the scope extends *beyond* an individual title, or questions for which the relevance is *specific* to a particular platforms release of a title. (i.e. [fighting-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fighting-games) might be used to ask questions about overall Fighting Game strategy, terminology, or meta-game concerns. [neogeo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neogeo) might apply to questions which apply *only* to the Neogeo release of a game, and not to other platforms on which it was released.)

From what I can see, most of these tags *don't* apply to the question at hand, which is perfectly adequately served by the game title. Others are unneeded and should be removed.

Comment: A keen observer will note that this is somewhat different from how tagging is handled at a lot of other SE sites. Suffice it to say that Tags at Gaming are strange and broken in a dozen little, and several very large ways, and most regulars are aware of the inconsistency - at the most fundamental level, the main thing to be aware of is that tagging questions with the title of the game is the most important, and *usually* only tag that's needed. Think long and hard about adding other tags - there's a reason most questions don't have more than one.